# Binary diff + patching across versions

Tags: binary-analysis, x86, tools, binary, patching

What are the current options for **binary patching** which works **across different versions** of the binary?

E.g. we created a binary patch for a specific version of a binary and want to apply that patch to another version of a binary which is slightly different to the original binary but identical in the 'area' (the function which needs to be patched)?

Of course this won't work in every case, but a good-enough solution for x64 would be fine.
Are there any tools, frameworks etc. available?

Comment: Exactly. Ideally considering architectural/binary specifics in the surrounding "pattern" which is likely to change across versions (for example, ignoring any absolute addressing).

Answer (score 1):

Version tracking in ghidra is exactly what you are looking for. Say you have two binaries with different versions. First, you need to analyze those binaries and save the analysis results (you can manually patch binary before or during this stage). Then click on version tracking symbol and create new version tracking session. Here, you can track and apply changes over from source to destination binary.

[image]

Please check their documentation in the help section, as shown in the image.

[image]

Please also checkout the complete video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K83T7iVla5s).

Comment: the problem is that ghidra's version tracking does not have a "similar functions" correlator, just an "identical functions" correlator. If the patch needs to be done in such a function (e.g. in a very large function where it is more likely that the function has been changed across versions) , "version tracking" does not help.

Comment: In that case you should definately take a look @ deepbindiff or radare's radiff2 project to get "similar functions" and "different functions" then apply patch using ghidra or any other tool